# Watson Studio customization

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio, watson-knowledge-catalog

I'm looking into the customization capabilities of Watson Studio and Watson Knowledge Catalog. My organization is interested in knowing whether our custom color palette can be integrated into Watson Studio or WKC. Also, can custom dashboard templates be imported in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Both customizations are not supported in Watson Knowledge Catalog or Watson Studio.